# Dynamic Navigation with responsive design and pure css

Tags: css, responsive-design

I built a few websites with responsive navigation already. There are many solutions for responsive designs of website navigation if you have  a static navigation.

However, for my current project I am building an user-individual dynamic navigation, so the number of navigation element as well as their contents are subject to change and are user individual. Therefore I tried different things with flexbox and floating layouts already but did not find a solution meeting my needs.

Do you have an idea how to fix the problem showed in the picture attached?

[image: Responsive Navigation]

I also attached some sample code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
        * {
            font-family: "Avenir";
        }
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
        header {
            background: #303ca2;
            color: white;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            display: flex;
        }
        h1 {
            font-size: 24px;
            margin: 0;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-weight: 400;
            padding: 10px;
            line-height: 40px;
            flex-shrink: 0;
        }
        nav {

        }
        nav ul {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            text-align: right;
        }

        nav ul li {
            list-style: none;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 16px;
            padding: 10px 10px;
            line-height: 40px;
        }

    </style>
   </head>
   <body>
    <header>
        <h1>Title Zone</h1>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>Navigation Elem 1</li>
                <li>Navigation Element 2</li>
                <li>Navigation 3</li>
                <li>Element 4</li>
                <li>Element 5</li>
                <li>Navigation 6</li>
                <li>Element n</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
   </header>

   </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need use media query to set what will appear in each screen size.
In the HTML file you will define all cases including a `div` tag "more" with yheir `li` tag
but when the screen size if less than a certain number this `div` will recive `display: none`
for example:

```
<ul>
  <li>element 1</li>
  <li>element 2</li>
  <li class="disabledOnMobile">element 3</li>
  <li class="disabledOnMobile">element 4</li>
  <div  class="activeOnMobile">more...
    <ul>
      <li>element 3</li>
      <li>element 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
</ul>
```

and with media query you can hide or show something based in the width screen like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .disabledOnMobile {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

hiding all tag with `disabledOnMobile` class (element 3 and 4 showing their only with "more")

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 400px) {
  .activeOnMobile {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Here we hide the `activeOnMobile` when the screen is bigger than 400px showing only element 3 and 4 that is outside `activeOnMobile` class

in your case you need add the hover on "more" and set anothers settings, it's only a example, you can also add a breakpoin in any screen size. To becobe it's easier you can use some library like bootstrap.
You can lear more about media query [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I do know how to use media queries. Unfortunately in this case  media queries do not solve the problem as you described, as the width of the single navigation elements is dynamic so I cannot say something like "on 400px screen I need to always see 3 navigation items", as I do not know how much space 3 navigation items will need without using javascript.

Comment: Hey brother without js you dont will have the best way, media query is the only way.
You can perfectly control some block for show or not based in the width screen, to do it in an easier way you can make 3 different navbar and set the display none our block based in the width screen, as I said, not is the best pratice since you will load unnecessary file in browser but if the project is small and you cannot use javascript, go ahead with media query